# Bootstrap MultiSelect - Customizing li template

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-multiselect

I am using David Stutz Multiselect for my application needs. I need to customize checkbox inside mutliselect to match with already customized checkboxes of my application.

In order to get my application checkbox, I need to have

```
<label class="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox">
       <i onclick="window.event.cancelBubble = true;"/>
    </input>
</label>
```

However, modifying templates to get the same is not working out.

```
('#workArea').multiselect({
    maxHeight: 200,
    includeSelectAllOption: true,
    buttonWidth: '100%',
    dropRight: true,
    templates: {
        li: '<li><a tabindex="0"><label><input><i></i></input></label></a></li>'
    }
});
```

Above results in

```
<li>
   <a tabindex="0">
      <label class="checkbox" title="Unassigned">
           <input type="checkbox" value="unassignedWorkArea"> Unassigned
      </label>         
   </a>
</li>
```

where `<i>` is missing. What do i need to do to make it work?